# Extending representations of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{F}_p) \times \mathrm{GL}(m,\mathbb{F}_p)$ to $\mathrm{GL}(n+m,\mathbb{F}_p)$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$In this question, representations means finite-dimensional complex representations.

Fix some $n,m \geq 2$ and some prime $p$.  I'm interested in representations $V$ of $\GL(n,\mathbb{F}_p)$ and $W$ of $\GL(m,\mathbb{F}_p)$ such that the action of $\GL(n,\mathbb{F}_p) \times \GL(m,\mathbb{F}_p)$ on $V \oplus W$ can be extended to an action of $\GL(n+m,\mathbb{F}_p)$.  This is trivially possible if both $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces equipped with trivial actions.  Are there any other examples?  My guess is that the answer is no, aside from maybe some sporadic examples for small $n$ and $m$ and $p$.

Note that it is important that we are restricting to complex representations.  If we allowed characteristic $p$ representations, then the standard representation of $\GL(n+m,\mathbb{F}_p)$ on $\mathbb{F}_p^{n+m}$ would give another example.

Comment: *"Are there any other examples" (than the trivial modules):* Obviously yes: when $V,W$ are the standard $n$- and $m$-dimensional modules.

Comment: @YCor: The standard representations are characteristic $p$ representations, but the question is looking for complex representations.

Comment: @AndyPutman ah, sure, thanks!

Comment: I'll note though that the example YCor pointed out is the only other example in characteristic p -- this can be seen by looking at weight spaces.   Similarly, the standard $n+m-1$ dimensional representation of $S_{n+m}$ is the only non-trivial irreducible representation of $S_{n+m}$ with a decomposition like this when we restrict to $S_n \times S_m$.  So any example would be very constrained in terms of both the composition factors in its reduction to characteristic p and its restriction to $S_{n+m}$.  I'm pretty sure no other examples exist, but I don't see an argument yet.

Comment: The question makes sense even when $m$ or $n$ is $1$, and might be easier then, and also help into having an intuition for the general case.

Comment: @Nate: Great observations!  I sent you an email about this.

Comment: @YCor: That's true.  I'm slightly less certain that there are no further examples when $m$ or $n$ is $1$.  For instance, as stated there are probably no further examples if you replace $GL$ with $SL$, but if $m$ or $n$ is $1$ you can find new examples for $SL$.